an identity about Fibonacci numbers (solved)
(original at https://i.sstatic.net/O9VjwlG1.png)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m \left(F_k^{4p-2}+F_{2m-k+1}^{4p-2}\right)
  = \sum_{k=1}^m \left\{ \left(F_k^2+F_{2m-k+1}^2\right)
    \sum_{i=0}^{2p-2} (-1)^i F_k^{4p-2i-4}F_{2m-k+1}^{2i}
    \right\}
$$
Could someone please explain how the identity in the figure was derived?
I tried to expand $(F_k + F_{2m-k+1})^{4p-2}$ using the binomial theorem and simplify, but I couldn't get the same result!
This question originates from Case 1 of Theorem 3 in the paper A New Formula for the Sum of the Sixth Powers of Fibonacci Numbers.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

@MartinR Okay, I will type it out later. Thank you for the reminder.

I've typed it in, since it's non-trivial. Please check that I've properly conveyed your intent.

@BrianTung Thank you very much for your help! I was a bit slow.

What happens with $m=1, p=1 ; ; ? ; ; ; $  Seems $m,p$   are largely independent; so what about $m=1, p=2 ; ; ? ; ; ; $

@WillJagy's comment prompts me to suggest that you add to your post where this came from, and if there are any conditions on the various terms, or if they have an interpretation that you can share, etc.

@Brian   good. As far as a lesson I have in mind,   the more intricate a sum, the more important it is for the student to write out, by hand, cases where the parameters are small. And, of course, sometimes the suggested formulas are just wrong.

Sources have been added, thank you for the reminder. Can anyone provide me with any assistance?

On the right side, the summation over $k$ is an expression which is an alternating sum all multiplied by a common factor. Did you try expanding this out and identifying the cancellations? By the way, the equation is true for any sequence $F_n$. No property of Fibonacci numbers is used.

@Somos Thank you for your response. I have solved it!
